# Running a program iteratively on subfolders using the find function in bash

Tags: .net, bash, for-loop, unix, find

I am trying to run a specific program by looping it through a bunch of subdirectories using the find function, yet nothing seems to happen. Here is my code:

```
for FILE in $(find ~/test -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.vcf'); do
    dotnet ~/Nirvana/Nirvana.dll \
     -c ~/Nirvana/Data/Cache/GRCh37/Both \
     --sd ~/Nirvana/Data/SupplementaryAnnotation/GRCh37 \
     -r ~/Nirvana/Data/References/Homo_sapiens.GRCh37.Nirvana.dat \
     -i $FILE \
     -o ~/test/annotTest/$FILE.vcf.gz 
done
```

Debugging with set -x seems to point to the following line:

```
++ find /home/test -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.vcf'
+ set +x
```

I'm pretty sure the program's parameters are correct, since they work when I use it on just one file, but looping it just does nothing.

Is there some error in my code that I'm not seeing?

Thanks!

Comment: How does the output of `for FILE in $(find ~/cfile/test -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.vcf'); do echo "$FILE" done` look like? In addition, please make sure the filenames do not contain blank characters (whitespaces, tabs, etc.). Your code breaks if it does.

Comment: Hmm, running that doesn't return anything - just goes to an empty bash line.

Edited to add: There are dashes "-" in the file names, could that cause a break as well?

Comment: @vanish007 dashes in the filenames shouldn't be a problem. Does `ls ~/test/*.vcf` list them?

Comment: @GordonDavisson `ls ~/test` will list the folders containing the files, but the command 'ls ~/test/*.vcf` says `ls: cannot access /home/test/*.vcf: No such file or directory`

Comment: @vanish007 The `-maxdepth 1` is telling `find` to search only in /home/test, not its subdirectories. `find` considers `~/test` to be at depth 0, items (files and directories) inside it to be at depth 1, and items inside the items (directories) inside `~/test` are at depth 2. So if you want it to find things in subdirectories, use `-maxdepth 2`. Although, actually, I'd just use a shell wildcard expression: `for file in ~/test/*/*.vcf`. (Note that lower- or mixed-case variable names are generally good practice).

Comment: @GordonDavisson that seems to have been the issue. I must have misinterpreted the [find documentation on -maxdepth](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Directories). I appreciate the help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-maxdepth 1` is telling `find` to search only in ~/test, not its subdirectories.

`find`'s idea of depth can be a little confusing: since you gave it `~/test` as the starting point for the search, it considers that to be at depth 0, items directly inside it to be at depth 1, and items inside *those* (i.e. in subdirectories of `~/test`) to be at depth 2. So if you want it to find things in subdirectories, use `-maxdepth 2`.

(Just to make things more confusing: if you use something like `find ~/test/* ...`, then the shell expands the `~/test/*` part into a list of files & directories in `~/test` and passes those as arguments to `find`. Therefore, since each of those was given to `find` as a separate starting point, each of those would be considered depth 0 in its own separate search. In this case, things in the subdirectories *would* be at depth 1.)

Actually, since you want to search at just a single level, I'd just use a shell wildcard expression:

```
for file in ~/test/*/*.vcf; do
```

(Note that lower- or mixed-case variable names are generally good practice, to avoid conflicts with the many all-caps names that have special meanings.)